# Replying directly to customer via transactional email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email, transactional-mail

I currently have a Magento 1.9 website which sends the standard transactional email when an order is completed and paid for, detailing a summary of the transaction and items.

How can I get a copy sent to my customer service email address, but either with the customer's email address in the from field, or set as a reply-to? The aim is that customer service agents can then simply reply to the order summary and the email goes directly to the customer.

My current set up is detailed below:

[image: Transactional Email Setup]

**Example Case**

A customer with the email address `customer@me.com` places an order and successfully completes checkout. `sales@mysite.com` send the order confirmation to the customer, and any additional recipients. My goal here is to have a Reply To header on all emails send out except the one that the customer receives. Therefore when a member of staff clicks 'Reply' to the order confirmation, it goes directly to `customer@me.com` rather than `sales@mysite.com`.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how we have ours configured. The carbon copy of the email that arrives at the inbox of the email address that you specify here also includes the `customer's email address`.

We then simply click `Reply All` and remove our own email addresses, leaving only the customers email. If we only click `Reply`, then it only includes the sending address, which is our sales@ address.

Comment: Thanks for the update, although I don't think I made it clear enough what I was asking, so I've updated my original question.